# Xcode 9 iOS Dynamic Font Size in Scroll View

Tags: ios, dynamic, scrollview, font-size, xcode9

I don't understand how to set Dynamic Font Size in Scroll View.
My AutoLayout is ok for all devices, but my font size stay at is initial size.

How can I make (exemple) Police système 20.0 for iPhones, and Police système 30.0 for iPads ?

Second question : why my scrollview is by default at the end of my text and not at the beginning ?

Thanks for your help.

I Join you 2 screenshot of the same page on iPhone 5SE & iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation).

iPhone 5SE

[image: 5SE]

iPad Pro 2nd Gen

[image: iPad Pro 2nd Gen]

Comment: What do you mean with ` scrollview is by default at the end of my text and not at the beginning`? What is `Police systeme`?

Comment: Please include any relevant code.

Comment: Have you watched any of the free WWDC videos on the topic of dynamic type? For instance: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/245/  . There are also blog posts on the topic. What have you tried so far? What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% you haven't used size classes yet. Here, have a look:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html

You need to *install* different fonts (for your particular case) according to different screen layouts.